# Bridge MQTT Connection between Servers with username

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to use mosquitto to bridge 2 other mqtt servers.

EXTERNAL > MOSQUITTO > INTERNAL

Internal requires a Username to be set. Is it possible to forward the username that is used to connect to MOSQUITTO to be forwarded to INTERNAL as well?

```
# connection internal

connection internal
address internal:1883

topic # out 0
topic # in 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, bridges are a one time thing, you do not get a bridge per connected user.

You can specify a username/password for (each end) of a bridge connection using the `remote_username`, `remote_password`, `local_username` and `local_password` config options as described in the [mosquitto.conf](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm45900608221648) man page.

The `local_` prefix are useful to ensure that ACLs are followed for connections and when `allow_anonymous false` is set.

Comment: It's not that I want to do it per connected user -> the bridge should be active for all users connecting. I need to forward the credentials to the next mqtt broker